# angular 4 post request to external application and callback to angular application with post request parameters

Tags: java, angular

I have an angular 4 application, when a button is clicked I would like to send the form details to an external java web application using post request and submit the form values to it. Once after redirecting to the external application and after confirmation on that page this has to redirect back to angular application with post request parameters and angular should able to retrieve these values. I am new angular and not sure how to acheive this. Could someone please help me by providing sample or steps to follow.

Thanks,
Hari.

Comment: Just follow the tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a [`FormGroup`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) element which will contain all of your form fields, then on `form submit` you need to create a [`request`](https://angular.io/guide/http) and add these values inside of it and fire off the request, then you need to handle the response and if you are using `Observables` you can do that inside of `subscribe` or if you are using `Promises`, you can do that inside of `then`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for you: 
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

1. You create a service class
2. You add a HTTPClient / HttpService to this class

You can call an external app by using something like:

```
passFormDetails(formValue: any): any {
  return this._httpService.post<any>('url of your external application goes here', formValue);
}
```

then in your component you would get an instance of this service class:

```
constructor(private _myService: MyService) {}
```

and call the function you just created:

```
someFunction() {
  this._myService.passFormDetails(this.formValue).subscribe(){
    next: (result) => {
      this.variableToStoreReturn = result;
    },
    error: (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you start, if you have any questions - please ask.